# Retrieve PHP Data from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The code below triggers the error callback function. Can you help me ? 
Actually the thing I'm trying do is get the data in the form in php and then send back these data in Ajax for further treatments

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div>
    <form id="user">
        NOM : <input type="text" name="name"/>
    </form>
        <button id="tst" onclick="SHOW();">CLICK</button>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function AFFICHER(){

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8012/myscript.php',
    data: $('#user').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log('ajax loading error...');
     return false;
    }
});


}
```

**My PHP**

```
<?php
$decoded = json_decode($_POST['data'],true);
foreach ($decoded as $value) {
   echo json_encode($value["name"]);
}

?>
```

**The error is**

[image]

Comment: `"The code below triggers the error callback function."` - And the error is... ?

Comment: A. there is no need to `json_decode()` the `$_POST` data, B. `$_POST['data']` isn't what you think it is, C. gather your array data inside the `foreach()` loop and `json_encode()` is *post* loop.

Comment: @David  error is "ajax loading error..." as in my callback

Comment: @JasonKrs: What's the *actual error*, not the message you write to the console (which doesn't contain any useful information about the problem)?

Comment: @JasonKrs - You're passing 3 arguments to the `error()` callback function which can offer you greater detail as to what is happening: `xhr, textStatus, errorThrown` Use those instead of a generic, non-informative error message such as "*ajax loading error*"

Comment: In your PHP, all you need to do for such a simple example is: `echo json_encode($_POST);` and be done with it. And since you're return data is expected to be `JSON` (which it will be), you cannot `console.log(result)` and expect results. You must access the keys directly, ie. `console.log(result.name)`, etc., as determined by the response data.

Comment: `$_POST` data doesn't exist. That's why. I *strongly* suggest you pick apart what's happening in your entire script, and learn what each piece is doing, ie. what [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is doing, how [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) works, how to handle errors properly (in your `error()` callback function), and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#user').serialize()` will leave you with a string such as `name=<input-value>` (*name* being the input name from your form input `name="name"`). The larger your form gets, the more values that will be stored in the data string, Eg. `name=marcus&phone=555-555-5555&location=interwebs`

To directly access those in your PHP script, you fetch them from the `$_POST` array (since you specified `type: 'POST'` in your `$.ajax()` settings):

`echo $_POST['name']; // marcus`

You need *not* run it through `json_decode()` since your data is not coming in as `JSON`, nor can/do you access `$_POST['data']` in the manner you are since that key does not exist in the `$_POST` array.

Your `foreach()` loop is redundant. The data in question (that you're looking to return) is already stored in the `$_POST` array.

Since your program is very basic, just encode the `$_POST` array and send it back. This is all you need in your PHP script:

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Then, since the response will be `JSON`, you can access the values by *key/property* in your `$.ajax().success()` callback function:

```
...
success: function(result) {
    console.log(result.name) // will log the value stored in 'name'
},
error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('Status: ' + textStatus, 'Error: ' + errorThrown)
}
```

I also added additional error handling so you can actually see what's going on should something go amiss. Learn to embrace errors to better understand your program. Generic errors such as "*didn't work!*", "*database connection failed!*", and/or "*ajax call no worky!*" are useless, for obvious reasons. They are merely breakpoints in the code, but offer no valuable feedback as to why they were executed.

Comment: Thanks Bro. Saved me

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$decoded = json_decode($_POST['data'],true);
foreach ($decoded as $value) {
   return[]=$value["name"];
}
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: `return[]` won't work. You're missing the `$` in `$return[]`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to decode the data on php file...
`dataType: "json"`  means the data type of response after ajax call is JSON.